# How to select creased edges?

Tags: modeling

I've gone through my model and manually selected edges to be creased. I'd like a way to reselect these creased edges long after they have been deselected. Could anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

In edge selection mode select a creased edge, go to select>select similar>crease and you should be fine